# Reuse SSL certificate from the personal certificate store across services such as RDP and Federated Sign In

Tags: ssl, active-directory, adfs2.0, windows-server-2022, acme

Using rmbolger's amazing posh-acme I deployed an SSL cert from let's encrypt into the personal certificate store of a Server 2022 VM following [this guide](https://www.dvolve.net/blog/2019/12/using-lets-encrypt-for-active-directory-domain-controller-certificates/).

I did some custom modifications to the script and I am rather happy with it, but I seem to be unable to make that certificate work with other Server 2022 services than LDAP. I would like to extend the current approach to also cover ADFS and certificates for terminal servers.

This script I wrote uses posh-acme to deploy the certificates on the server in the personal store. For the record I pasted the code below.
Services like RDP or Federated Sign-In don't seem to pick it up though.

```
# Cloud Flare requires a simple API token, but we need to secure the string to keep it safe
$token = ConvertTo-SecureString 'thatisactuallysecret' -AsPlainText -Force
$pArgs = @{CFToken=$token}

# The ActiveDirectory PowerShell module is installed by default on DCs
$dc = Get-ADDomainController $env:COMPUTERNAME
$certNames = @($dc.HostName, $dc.Domain)

# This is optional, but usually a good idea.
$notifyEmail = 'dev@gmservice.app'

$certParams = @{
    Domain = $certNames
    DnsPlugin = 'Cloudflare'
    PluginArgs = $pArgs
    AcceptTOS = $true
    Install = $true
    Contact = $notifyEmail  # optional
    Verbose = $true         # optional
}

New-PACertificate @certParams
```